# Titaniumn app to not run in background - Without changing info.plist

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to make my app **not** run in the background using Appcelerator Titanium, and have only come accross the solution which suggests editing the info.plist file after the build has completed.

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

This works as expected, however this means I would have to put this in each time I do a full rebuild on the app. Does anybody know of anything i can put in the tiapp.xml file in order to acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy the built info.plist into your Resources folder once. From http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/04/adding-custom-fonts-to-ipad.html

"As an update for those using 1.3+, we’ve changed the way that custom Info.plist files are handled in Titanium. You’ll want to copy the Info.plist that is generated for your project under build/iphone into your project root folder. You can edit this file to add any custom Info.plist changes. From now on, Titanium compiler will always use this Info.plist."

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i wanted, Thanks!